# Low Disk Space On Linux

Tags: linux

I get a low disk space (71% in use out of 10GB)

```
df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  9.8G  6.5G  2.8G  71% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   3.0G  128K  3.0G   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/af9b99b8-9f61-4eee-aa51-d5113368814d  9.8G  6.5G  2.8G  71% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   6.0G     0  6.0G   0% /run/shm
tmpfs                                                   1.0G  6.1M 1018M   1% /mnt/tmp
```

But When I run this command to check, i only get 1.5G used

```
sudo du --all --one-file-system / | awk '{if($1 > 102400) print int($1/1024) "MB" " " $2 }'
117MB /var/cache/apt/archives
164MB /var/cache/apt
168MB /var/cache
132MB /var/lib/apt/lists
132MB /var/lib/apt
148MB /var/lib
416MB /var
115MB /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/drivers
159MB /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel
163MB /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
163MB /lib/modules
175MB /lib
223MB /usr/lib
146MB /usr/local/lib
106MB /usr/local/share
267MB /usr/local
199MB /usr/share
754MB /usr
1541MB /
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Note that you aren't seeing any of the "tmptfs" cases here. That would be my note.

Comment: I prefer this command to see top level directory space usage. `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / `

Comment: Try `du -b` instead, in order to read real byte occupation

Answer (score 2):

If a process has an open file handle to a large file which has been deleted, then it will still appear in the disk usage, but the file will be inaccessible and will not appear under `du`.

```
# Create large file
$ df .
Filesystem   512-blocks      Used  Available Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2 1951845952 284650968 1666682984    15% 35645369 208335373   15%   /

$ du -s
2604488     .

# Remove the file -note how the du result decreases

$ rm junk

$ df .
Filesystem   512-blocks      Used  Available Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2 1951845952 285526568 1665807384    15% 35754819 208225923   15%   /

$ du -s
61728       .

# Kill the process holding the file - now the df usage decreases

Filesystem   512-blocks      Used  Available Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2 1951845952 282561000 1668772952    15% 35384123 208596619   15%   /
$ du -s
61736       .
```